# Generate the hour and day at dataframe with only Minute and Second data - Python

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have this dataframe (example of how it changes after an hour). The problem is that it is a dataframe of 160,000 rows and where it only advances in hours during a month, so assuming that the data is complete, I wanted to generate the time and day of the month. The seconds are with a decimal.

```
105    59:12.9
106    59:22.8
107    59:32.9
108    59:43.0
109    59:53.1
110    00:03.2
111    00:13.3
112    00:22.3
113    00:32.4
114    00:42.6
```

From what I have seen, the datatime library in pandas does not allow resample in this format. I would like to obtain the data in the form   2012/1/1 00:00:00 (assuming it starts on January 1, 2012).

Is there any way to do it with pandas? or should I do some iterative function over the minutes?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  It's not at all clear what you want.  You speak of days and hours, but your data shows what you describe as minutes and seconds.  You say that you want to iterate over minutes, but your data are not at a regular interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do what you want without iterating over the list, but you could do that with Pandas' apply method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Here's a rough example:

```
df = YourDataFrame
day = datetime.date(2012, 1, 1)
hour = 0
last = datetime.strptime("00:00.0","%M:%S.%f")
def expandtime(time):
    t = datetime.strptime(time,"%M:%S.%f")
    if t < last:
        if hour >= 23:
            day = day + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            hour = 0
        else:
            hour += 1
    last = t
    return day + timedelta(hours=hour, minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)

df.apply(expandtime, axis=1)
```